# XML parsing in jquery doesn't seem to work for me

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

I have a static html page `weather.html`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Delhi",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: parseXml
            });
        });
        function parseXml(xml) {
           $(xml).find("weather").each(function() {
            alert($(this).attr("temp_c"));
            });
       }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

The alert doesn't seem to get displayed in the page when i inspected trough firebug i found this,

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{08ba4230-2feb-48d3-969e-b53579b07b52} Line Number 1, Column 1:
^
```

also function `parseXml` doesn't seem to get called...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access distant domains using AJAX. See [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You are trying to access a script located on `google.com`, so unless this is page is on hosted on this same domain it won't work. The only way to make this work is to setup a proxy server script on your server to which you will send the AJAX call and it will delegate the call to `google.com`. Another alternative is to use [JSONP](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2/Ajax#Cross-Domain_getJSON_.28using_JSONP.29) but the distant script needs to support it.

Comment: Yes, either using a server side script that will act as a proxy or JSONP (works only with `GET` requests).