# Loading XML using $.ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XML parsing in jquery doesn't seem to work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210690/xml-parsing-in-jquery-doesnt-seem-to-work-for-me)
>   [Access-Control-Allow-Origin error sending a jQuery Post to Google API's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114436/access-control-allow-origin-error-sending-a-jquery-post-to-google-apis)

I'm trying to load data from Google's weather API.  When I run this code:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=13210",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {   } 
});
```

I get the following message: `XMLHttpRequest` cannot load http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=13210. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Why am I getting this message?  I am new to loading XML into jquery.

Comment: Seems like this was asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114436/access-control-allow-origin-error-sending-a-jquery-post-to-google-apis

Comment: check edit ansser of mine ...

Comment: dont forget to upvote and mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want ..

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way you can directly load the XML from

```
http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=13210
```

using only jQuery/JavaScript. The [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents that. And Google does not send an [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header either (which could allow access).

The only way is to load it from server-side.